# Boot option not available to boot Kali Linux (installed along side Windows 8)

Tags: linux, windows, windows-8, boot

i have Sony Vaio laptop with pre-installed Windows 8. I installed kali linux (in UEFI mode) alongside with windows 8. On first restart, I got both the option in the boot menu i.e., to either start kali linux or windows 8. I chose windows 8 first. After I restarted again, that dual boot option is not showing anymore and windows 8 is starting automatically. What should I do to get dual boot option to boot either Kali Linux or Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider getting third party boot menu software. Windwos 8 is not to natively boot Kali Linux, so I'd go with 3rd party software that is made to recognize multiple OS's.

**EDIT** So per the comment below, I have decided to revise my answer. You can install A boot loader like this one [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) it will list all the OS's installed and you can choose the one that you would like.

Comment: Your answer is kind of nebulous.  It points in a direction that someone could research for an answer, but it isn't information someone could follow to solve the problem.  With a little more rep, you could put this kind of advice in a comment.  Answers should be definitive solutions.

Answer (score 0):

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/6

that does sound a lot like your problem... 
Also since GRUB should be able to boot linux and windows (and ...), you might consider using it instead of the boot menu.

Comment: External links can become unavailable, in which case your answer would have little value (other than general advice to research GRUB).  Super User's purpose is to build a knowledgebase for long-term reference, so link-only answers are discouraged because of that.  Links should be used for attribution and further information, but the essential information should be included in the answer.